# How to execute a task as administrator transparently in Windows

Tags: c#, c++, windows, winapi

I would like to emulate (programmatically) the behavior of Windows in some elevation situations. For example you can see the wireless password, without having to acknowledge elevation to administrator (In Wireless Network Properties > Show characters).

In this scenario, there is no windows pop up to request confirmation of elevation. There is simply a friendly icon that shows that the action requires the user to be an administrator.

Comment: you need to get MS to sign AND ship your code as direct part of Windows in some specific "secure" directories... any other option means to "hack" the OS... I am pretty sure that this is not possible for anyone outside MS... so I don't see how you can achieve what you want...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason that there are no popups in some scenarios is UAC auto-elevation.

Here is an excerpt from [this article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2009.07.uac.aspx#id0560031) written by Mark Russinovich

> The reason that elevation of (most) Windows executables in the two middle settings doesn't result in a prompt is that the system "auto elevates" Windows executables. First, what does Windows define as a Windows executable in this context? The answer depends on several factors, but two things must hold: it must be digitally signed by the Windows publisher, which is the certificate used to sign all code included with Windows (it's not sufficient to be signed by Microsoft, so Microsoft software that's not shipped in Windows isn't included); and it must be located in one of a handful of "secure" directories.

That means your executable must be signed by Microsoft, and it has to be in those "secure" directories. Windows does not auto-elevate everything.

Comment: To quote your quote: _"It's not sufficient to be signed by Microsoft"_.